# How to tell my HTTPS connection to a site uses PFS?

Tags: tls, web-browser, chrome, firefox, forward-secrecy

Does the browser have a UI for displaying the details about the TLS connection to the website, besides the "secure/insecure" icon?

Answer (score 3):

In Google Chrome:

1. click on the padlock icon:

[image: click on the padlock icon]

2. click on "Details":

[image: click on "Details"]

3. click on reload:

[image: click on reload]

4. In the Security Panel, click on the URL under "Main Origin":

[image: In the Security tab, click on the URL under "Main Origin"]

5. look at value of "Key Exchange" under the "Connection" section:

[image: look at value of "Key Exchange" under the "Connection" section]

If the key exchange begins with "ECDHE" or "CECPQ1"[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADFPW.png) then you have PFS.

In Mozilla Firefox:

1. click on the padlock icon:

[image: click on the padlock icon]

2. click on the expander thingy on the right side of the popup:

[image: click on the expander thingy on the right side of the popup]

3. click on "More Information" on the bottom side of the popup:

[image: click on "More Information" on the bottom side of the popup]

4. look at name of cipher suite in Page Info popup window:

[image: look at name of cipher suite in Page Info popup window]

If the name of the cipher suite begins with `TLS_DHE_` or `TLS_ECDHE` then you have PFS.

I did not find a way to get Microsoft Edge to divulge the used TLS cipher suite in the UI - you need to sniff the traffic with wireShark or equivalent.

I don't have a Safari available right now, but I'll add that later if I find a way to the Safari to display the cipher suite.

1 - https://security.googleblog.com/2016/07/experimenting-with-post-quantum.html